# Does Google Maps overlap locationListener method?

Tags: android, google-maps, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I am using Google Maps on my project mainActivity. I need to get location in background too, so created a service which includes locationListener. It works properly when enable/disable provider but does not update the location. May google maps cause that?

Answer (score 0):

I feel that you might be battling with the issue regarding the limits imposed on the background location updates for android O (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits). You might consider calling a foreground service. For a guide on how to employ location logging in a foreground service here is some code that I've made previously (https://github.com/kris-geyer/pegLog)